# Slater-Velez permutation

Tags: code-golf, sequence, permutations

Let's build a sequence of positive integers.  The rule will be that the next number will be the smallest number which:

- It hasn't already appeared in the sequence
- Its absolute difference from the number preceding it wouldn't be equal to any previous absolute difference between consecutive elements.

### Task

Your task is to implement this sequence.  You may use [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) defaults, found in the [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being better.

### Example

As an example let's construct the first couple of terms. The first term is `1` since it's the smallest positive integer.  After that comes `2`.

```
Sequence: 1, 2
Diffs:     1
```

`3` is the next smallest number, but it's difference from `2` is the same as the difference between `1` and `2`, so `4` is the next term.

```
Sequence: 1, 2, 4
Diffs:     1, 2
```

Now `3` *still* can't be added because it's difference from `4` is `1`, `5` and `6` also can't be added because their diffs are `1` and `2`.  So the smallest number is `7`.

```
Sequence: 1, 2, 4, 7
Diffs:     1, 2, 3
```

Now `3` can be added, since it's difference from `7` is `4` which we haven't seen before.

```
Sequence: 1, 2, 4, 7, 3
Diffs:     1, 2, 3, 4
```

Since the diffs count up to `4` we know the next one is *at least* `5`, so the next number is at least `8`.  `8` hasn't appeared so we can add it.

```
Sequence: 1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 8
Diffs:     1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

### Test cases

This sequence is [OEIS A081145](http://oeis.org/A081145).  Here are the first few terms taken from OEIS:

```
1, 2, 4, 7, 3, 8, 14, 5, 12, 20, 6, 16, 27, 9, 21, 34, 10, 25, 41, 11, 28, 47, 13, 33, 54, 15, 37, 60, 17, 42, 68, 18, 45, 73, 19, 48, 79, 22, 55, 23, 58, 94, 24, 61, 99, 26, 66, 107, 29, 71, 115, 30, 75, 121, 31, 78, 126, 32, 81, 132, 35, 87, 140, 36, 91, 147, 38, 96, 155, 39
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 70 bytes

```
a={0,p:=1}
while[print(d:=p)]:
 while(s:={p-d,-d*d})&a:d-=1
 a|=s;p-=d
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCoMwFED3nOJDoSTWFN1KSgaXXsI6CD9iwJqQpK1iPUkXl_ZO3qZFnR48Hu_9tX2oTTvN1x2Yh3JOowLrdBsgGDBt0wMaCLWCSjsfIE0SCMrdPEFVrSHt4kzmqtOhOOSLKaJ_xkR2tMZSRjv2uYeKn-ZLKYcktkKmI3nWulFrTlFIywpBYJHUCzlYjjHHCEe2LwVymRIoX9KfLZe43qYNG38)

-1 each thanks to @xnor and @ovs.

Prints the sequence infinitely. Avoids the need for two storage lists by using the negative absolute difference.

Comment: Nice idea with the negatives! Here's [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8DW0DrRttqglqs8IzMnVSHPytbQiksBzNEotrKtztOpS0wq1ijQzdOs1VRLtMrTtjXkUkissS22LijKzCvRKLCyzdP8/x8A "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). Might be possible to shorten the initialization.

Comment: Brownie points for golfing my modified `print` implementation!

Comment: `-abs(p-n)` would work as well, because a difference of `0` never happens, which means `-(p-n)**2` works, which saves a byte if we keep track of `w=p-n` instead of `n`: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCoMwFED3nOJDoSStKbqVlAwuvYR1ESMGrPkkaaNYT9LFpb2Tt2lRpwePx3t_sfe1aaf5tgPzVNbqUgFa3XrwBkzb9FAa8LWCSlvnIYlj8MreHSlVtYa0i1KZqU77_JgtJj_8MybSExqkjHbs8_AVP8_XQg5xhEImIwm1btSa0yAkslwQWCR1Qg7IQ8TDIYxsX4jAZUIAuQyX4iXdeps2bPwB

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
~l.ℕ₁ᵐ≠s₂ᵇ-ᵐȧᵐ≠∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy5H71HL1EdNjQ@3TnjUuaD4UVPTw63tukDeieUQoUcdy///NzT4HwUA)

Returns a list of the `n` first elements of the sequence.

#### Explanation

We basically describe the properties of the sequence: a list of positive integers, that are all different, and where each 2-element substring difference is unique.

```
~l.                Output is a list of length <Input>
  .ℕ₁ᵐ             Output contains strictly positive integers
  .   ≠            All elements in the output are different
  .    s₂ᵇ         Find all sublists of 2 consecutive elements in the Output
          -ᵐ       Map subtraction
            ȧᵐ     Map absolute value
              ≠    All results must be different
               ∧   Implicit labelling of elements in the output to match these constraints
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>15</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
λλû¥+λ«∞sKн
```

-4 bytes thanks to @ovs.

Outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//867zrvDu8KlK867wqviiJ5zS9C9//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
λ           # Start a recursive environment
            # to output the infinite sequence
            # Implicitly starting with a(0)=1
            # Where every following a(n) is calculated as follows:
            #  (implicitly push a(n-1))
 λ          #  Push a list of all previous terms: [a(0),a(1),...,a(n-1)]
  û         #  Palindromize this list: [a(0),a(1),...,a(n-1),...,a(1),a(0)]
   ¥        #  Pop and push its forward differences
    +       #  Add the implicit a(n-1) to each
     λ«     #  Merge the list of previous terms to this list
       ∞    #  Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
        s   #  Swap so our earlier created list is at the top again
         K  #  Remove all those values from the infinite positive list
          н #  Pop and leave just the first value
            # (after which the infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: I think [`λλû¥+λ«∞sKн`](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//867zrvDu8KlK867wqviiJ5zS9C9//8) works for 11. (`λû¥` is shorter than `λ¥D(«`)

Comment: @ovs Thanks for the -4. I should have known just removing them from the infinite list and getting the first remaining would be shorter after I had to introduce those variables for the inner find_first-loop. But apart from that: since when is `ü¥` being `¥D(«` a thing?! :S

Comment: That is `û` not `ü` ;). There is no special meaning for this, but the negative forward difference are the forward differences of the reverse (as long as you don't care about the order), and `û` appends the reverse to the list.

Comment: @ovs Ah lol.. I misread. Yeah ok, `û` is the palindrome builtin. Ok, now it makes a lot more sense than when I read `ü`, haha. I was so confused for a moment! xD

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 43 bytes

```
{x,{y+(1<#?:\#'!'1_-':x,y)|/x=y}[x]/1}/[;1]
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwVissOgjAURPf9ihoWaLz00oqCqPFD0BiCBYy8pMUUkX+3Lk5mzmTyeDIwjeslPzrn+OK4C5ffPDc2MK6+aE7jnJgr8hmTA78SktPAwgUhSEqtOxUjZu1dFm2VM6XT7ClNVqZNIVnW1vgapNKPtlEoAj/aR6iqVMvee8tKfrxO9vWg0/+BEA5UAA2AhkA3QCOg3MrWhp2FD3Rnq0WEjLEfaCMzbg==)

Takes the number of terms to generate (0-indexed, so passing `0` generates the sequence up to position 0, `4` generates the sequence up to position 4, etc etc.)

- `{...}/[;1]` set up a do-reduce, run for the inputted number of times, seeded with `1` (the first term of the sequence)

  - `{...{...}[x]/1}` set up a converge-reduce, fixing `x` (the sequence generated so far) and seeded with `1`

    - `(1<#?:\#'!'1_-':x,y)` determine if the current value has a different absolute difference than the rest of the terms in the sequence so far

      - `x,y` append the value being tested to the sequence so far
      - `1_-':` take the differences between successive items
      - `#'!'` take the absolute value of these differences
      - `1<#?:\` determine if the differences are all distinct (i.e. none are repeated)
    - `(...)|/x=y` set up a max-reduce (i.e. any), seeded with the check described above and run over the sequence compared to the value being tested (for equality)
    - `y+` add this result to the current value being tested; if the value meets both checks, it will be unchanged and end the converge-reduce
  - `{x,...}` append the next term in the sequence and feed it to the next iteration of the do-reduce

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 107 bytes

```
e l=[last l+x*v|v<-zipWith((abs.).(-))l$1:l,x<-[-1,1]]++l
f n=head$filter(flip notElem$e$f<$>[0..n-1])[1..]
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDsIgFADQ3VP8gQGkkOJoiptncCAMGCEQP5QU0jTGu2N884uuvT3iGB5QG3StA/LjvH/3RXxSfaQeKXXPJpmkgjEk6orTsQgj1KSs5RxPAYqO3r1ISNj9RgOmCmXtd/SZeBIWcjOzlEUoy4yS0o7sUgENdUulA4HsKgT4n8tsxw8)

-3 bytes thanks to AZTECCO

Comment: Nice answer, (I posted mine anyway because its different) , you can steal from mine (1:l) instead of $tail l , that's all the help I can give, but I feel like that's still something..

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 97 bytes

```hs
(#)=notElem
g=(iterate(\l->l++[[x|x<-[1..],x#l,abs(x-last l)#zipWith((abs.).(-))l(1:l)]!!0])[]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixDoMgEADQvV@BocNdFKIdG@nWb3CgDDQhSnpSIzeQxn@nTi95i8@fQFQrSDTpy08K62U2EDnsngO8SD2oba0tRxmVHbR2XZHU@XeGoshnFoTyF7cp8gJwtkYNCpFguBO6pukd2hOsq49JGLHtMbG4zuLW1z8)

- returns first *n* elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 84 bytes

A full program printing the sequence forever.

```javascript
for(a=[];i=1;print(p=i),a.push(i))while(a.some(q=v=>v==i|(i-p)**2==(q-(q=v))**2))i++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoMwEAXQ68yoEXQlyO9FSheDWPyl1jHRdNO7p7h872XZ0hTpR8hDKc8tiuH@GIlu9MjPIQ5qY62faRGqfhe@Z7E2bessOzJuGeBPGFyrqgdkD9frJVXWdSl/)

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>66</s>  65 bytes

Using [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240900/58563)'s nice idea.

```javascript
for(s=p={};i=1;print(s[q]=s[i]=p=i))while(s[q=i-p,q*=-q]|s[i])i++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SKPYtsC2utY609bQuqAoM69Eozi6MNa2ODozFiiRqalZnpGZkwoStM3ULdAp1LLVLYytAUlrZmpr//8PAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
(λ¾₌‡¯ȧtnεc¾nc∨¬;ṅ…⅛
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIozrvCvuKCjOKAocKvyKd0bs61Y8K+bmPiiKjCrDvhuYXigKbihZsiLCIiLCI1Il0=)

I'm probably going to take the L to better algorithms, but that's okay with me. Prints the first n numbers.

### Explained

```
(λ¾₌‡¯ȧtnεc¾nc∨¬;ṅ…⅛
(                     # input times:
 λ..............;ṅ    #   find the first number N where:
   ₌                  #     the 
  ¾ ‡¯ȧ               #     absolute values of the deltas of the global array
          c           #     contains
  ¾    tnε            #     the absolute difference of the last item of the global array and N
              ∨¬      #     nor
           ¾nc        #     does the global array contain N
                  …⅛  #   print N and add to the global array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) List::Util, 64 bytes

```perl
$l=@a=0..1e3;$a[$l]=0,say$l while$l=first{$_&&!$d{abs$_-$l}++}@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lx9Yh0dZAT88w1dhaJTFaJSfW1kCnOLFSJUehPCMzJxWoIC2zqLikWiVeTU1RJaU6MalYJV5XJadWW7vWIfH//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9fTKLS6ysQksyoXqAQmWmeoYGAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 76 bytes

```r
while(k<-1){p=print(+T[1])
while((p-k)^2%in%diff(T)^2|k%in%T)k=k+1
T=c(k,T)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVI9tG11CzusC2oCgzr0RDOyTaMFaTCyKlUaCbrRlnpJqZp5qSmZamEQLk1GSDuCGa2bbZ2oZcIbbJGtk6IZq1//8DAA)

Prints the sequence infinitely.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>74</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```r
repeat T=c((u=1:(T*5))[!u%in%T&!(u-print(+T[1]))^2%in%diff(T)^2][1],T)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vyi1IDWxRCHENllDo9TW0EojRMtUUzNasVQ1M081RE1Ro1S3oCgzr0RDOyTaMFZTM84IJJGSmZamEQLkxAIFdUI0//8HAA)

Outputs the sequence indefinitely.

Note (from [OEIS A081145](https://oeis.org/A081145)) that "*The points appear to lie on three straight lines of slopes roughly 0.56, 1.40, 2.24 (click "[graph](https://oeis.org/A081145/graph)")*".
If true, then `a(n)` should always be less than or equal to `a(n-1)` multiplied by about `2.24/0.56`, or `4`.  So here we only search in the range from `1` up to `a(n-1)` times `5` (to be on the safe side).

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 32 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

Prints the sequence without end.

```
{∇⍵,⍨⊃k~⍨⍳+/k←⍵,(⎕←⊃⍵)+2-/⍵,⌽⍵}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRR/uj3q06j3pXPOpqzq4D0b2btfWzH7VNAIlrPOqbCmJ2NQN5mtpGuvpg1T17gVSt4f//AA)

```
{∇⍵,⍨⊃k~⍨⍳+/k←⍵,(⎕←⊃⍵)+2-/⍵,⌽⍵}1 ⍝ full program that prints the sequence indefinitely
{                             }  ⍝ recursive function taking the previous numbers as right argument ⍵
                       2-/⍵,⌽⍵   ⍝ forward and backward differences of consecutive numbers in ⍵
                 ⎕←⊃⍵            ⍝ print (and return) the previous value
                      +          ⍝ add this to all the differences
                                 ⍝ all these results are not allowed because of the absolute difference rule
              ⍵,                 ⍝ prepend the previous sequence values
            k←                   ⍝ store this list in k
          +/                     ⍝ take the sum of k (this is always larger than the maximum value)
      k~⍨⍳                       ⍝ [1 .. sum(k)] without the values in k
     ⊃                           ⍝ take the first (lowest) value
  ⍵,⍨                            ⍝ prepend to the sequence values
 ∇                               ⍝ recursive function call with updated list
                               1 ⍝ call above function with value 1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>81</s> 77 bytes

*4 bytes saved by xnor*

```hs
(?)=notElem
q@(a:b)!x=a:[(z:q)!(d:x)|z<-[1..],d<-[abs$a-z],z?q,d?x]!!0
[1]![]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcYxCsMgFADQPaf4HzIomJB0lIpdegpx@EFJQ4ypjYNI7277pveia/chtMY0V/HMz@CPLj0YyYVjUSQNqzJxZE4W/q33wczjaIX7h5arp6FaUXUSTheLOHWrMrNFY9tBWwQF788WM/SZdg@3Cdb2Aw)

I gave it a day so I thought I'd give this a spin in Haskell myself.  `[1]![]` gives an infinite list of the results.

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcYxCsMgFADQPaf4HzIomJB0lIpdegpx@EFJQ4ypjYNI7277pveia/chtMY0V/HMz@CPLj0YyYVjUSQNqzJxZE4W/q33wczjaIX7h5arp6FaUXUSTheLOHWrMrNFY9tBWwQF788WM/SZdg@3Cdb2Aw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
≔¹ηＦＮ«≔¹ζＷ∨№υζ№υ±↔⁻ζη≦⊕ζ⊞υζ⊞υ±↔⁻ζη≔ζη⟦Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY8/D4IwEMVn@BQdrwkmMjMRJgaQ3TgUrLRJaUn/aFLjZ69FCDp5072Xl9@9GxjRgyIihNIYPkrIM8Rwkd6URlDL2dnWTT3VgDF6psk35GMoeTAuKIKThko5acEtfoZ20dKRWAplb5RwcWm4dAb8cuIzqCHzhqzloOlEpaXXDd45w1bij/hPLPaGfn0j6TSPVc4VMRY8vkTrFUJ@DIe7eAM) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` terms. Explanation: Uses @pxeger's trick to avoid keeping track of two sets.

```
≔¹η
```

Start with the previous term being `1`. This gives a zero difference for the first term, which doesn't conflict with anything else.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Process `n` terms.

```
≔¹ζ
```

Start looking for the next term with `1`.

```
Ｗ∨№υζ№υ±↔⁻ζη
```

While the term, or its negated absolute difference with the previous term, already exists in the predefined empty list, ...

```
≦⊕ζ
```

... increment the potential next term.

```
⊞υζ
```

Save the term to the predefined empty list.

```
⊞υ±↔⁻ζη
```

Save the negated absolute difference to the predefined empty list.

```
≔ζη
```

Save the term as the previous term.

```
⟦Ｉζ
```

Output the term on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```ruby
a=0,p=1;loop{d=p p;d-=1while[]!=a&s=[p-d,-d*d];p,=a=s|a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7NasMwEIRfRb30UNZg/ViyMHqSkIOLCi0EIhpCKW2f3f0mh2W1O59m9vP@@n0ce5ttNL9drtfx09twY@tT81/vH5e30/mp7c@3dhpTt6m/9PM2rO3t9rv/HYc3F8wlc8VcNLea8wwLjXWYzWWeVECvNPgI4FECVGL28uBjAvF4RGoRgx7ZZVhPTzhmBYhFK3Aez8Rc5I2@sA/6z67iEaiMf5XOGVnnzJgFFuURrhQSyuNmnUcVxYiPeK7C9Iggq45M8BG1StHZUXGyVn6s/w)

Stolen from pxeger Python answer, and then thanks pxeger again for -2 bytes.

## (previously) [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 76 bytes

```ruby
a,*r=1;loop{r<<a-a=p(1.step.find{|b|q=1;r.all?{|c|[b]&[q-=c,a-c,c+a]==[]}})}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5LboQwEESv4lWUj0HjDzZWxspBEAtDEmkklGFIsoiAs5PXs2i1u@u5qpff4e84in5esnmdrtd5Xc7nUpU8P5r6@@djrj8vX@/rNmw3gKUu0/S2buPWDf1Dd6vyqEs16vGl9Dl3/b4/7cdhtLJaea2iVk6rVivD0NBY25NWgSdl0RMN3gEYFAvlmY148NGDGDwc1QiD7tgFWEP3OAYJEBYtwhk8PXMUb/SGvZX/7BIelgr4J9E5I8g5J8wsi3gPlxQS4v1mOY@KEiO8w7MVTB4OpJUjPbxDTaLI2U7ixFryXfoH)

Comment: `p(d=p)` -> `d=p p`

Comment: Also you don't need the `*` at the start

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>149</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>132</s></sup> 131 bytes

```cpp
#import<set>
void f(int&n){std::set<int>s;int i,p=n,x;for(n=1;p--;s.insert({n=i,-x*x}))for(i=0;s.count(++i)|s.count(-(x=n-i)*x););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVLbbqMwEH3nK0ZZqcKJqcIlEMrlZbVf0eQBgdO1NjEI3BZtNr@@2TPQbFqksWfmnDkz2K67zquPlXm5Xr/pU9f2Nh@ULZ23Vjd0cLWxD0acB9s8PSGfIy6HDCtp2RVGjtmh7V1T@FnnednwqM2geuueTaGlNy7HixBM0MUaYN2@GuuuVlr8uQWeOxbG02I5ikxkF8xg6uNroyjX7WB7VZ1K5557U7Vt@9Lh/qdKG1ecHcJXt2awNA05U6Y5SY0dItVQQWdfUiApkpRICiVtJfkINtiQDtaSYriwAHiKDfwQBB9IAFaE2GcNFEag@NAIYRvmAA@Ri8H1sUdQjLkBc4El4PnQjBAnrA18g3zA9cil0AhgMfRTxjFGzOOsIRYgkUzNuQs6JNPMPB4s4TbMD6G5ZRo7IShbHjICPwSaMsJjh9yOpbl/mF6yT8dX/6z6JVZV/1L9854PbbEbfwS7Mf0O2ywkfY7DxUc17pfc6UWYRo0oW2cfbv7/Bh4H/Vu5IiNcPkOC5ovjj0styuaaFfnZF8gAsvfUwbXiK0GBcOvzPIns74TpTeCpWcpzSGFZkFdigWfncPJvv62Kwu6n/M4sZpmLc7n@rQ/H6mW4eu//AA)

*Uses [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)'s idea from his [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240900/9481) so only one `std::set` is needed.*

Inputs an integer \$n\$.
Returns (through re-assignment of the input value) the \$1\$-indexed \$n^{\text{th}}\$ term of the Slater-Valez sequence.